# From gauge anomaly to chiral anomaly

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, quantum-anomalies, chirality

Suppose the theory of chiral Weyl fermion (say, left) $\psi_{L}$, which interacts with abelian gauge field. This theory contains **gauge anomaly**, which I write in the form
$$
\frac{dQ_{L}}{dt} = \text{A},
$$
where $Q_{L}$ is the left charge and $A$ is anomaly function.

The same thing is true about right fermion $\psi_{R}$. If the gauge field is vector (not axial vector), then
$$
\frac{dQ_{R}}{dt} = -\text{A},
$$
The underlying reason for this is that the dynamics of theory generates anomalous commutator between canonical momentums of EM field (the electric field $\mathbf E$): pcecisely,
$$
\tag 0 [E_{i}(\mathbf x), E_{j}(\mathbf y)]_{L/R} = -i\Delta^{ij}_{L/R}(\mathbf A, \mathbf y)\delta (\mathbf x - \mathbf y),
$$
where $L,R$ denotes the subspaces of left and right fermions. This gives (see [the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289398/anomalous-commutators-and-gauge-anomaly)) the precise form of anomaly $A$:
$$
\frac{dQ_{L/R}}{dt} = \text{A} = \int d^{3}\mathbf r E_{i}(\mathbf r)\partial_{j}\Delta^{ij}_{L/R}(\mathbf A, \mathbf r)
$$

Suppose now we take the "direct sum" of left and right representations:
$$
\psi = \psi_{L} \oplus \psi_{R}
$$
In this case, as we know, there is no gauge anomaly of vector charge $Q_{\text{vector}}$,
$$
\tag 1 \frac{dQ_{\text{vector}}}{dt} = \frac{dQ_{L}}{dt} + \frac{dQ_{R}}{dt} = \text{A} - \text{A} = 0,
$$ 
but there is the chiral anomaly of axial charge $Q_{\text{axial}}$,
$$
\tag 2 \frac{dQ_{\text{axial}}}{dt} =\frac{dQ_{L}}{dt} - \frac{dQ_{R}}{dt} =\text{A}+\text{A}= 2\text{A}
$$
Since the vector current is the gauge current, the total contribution into anomalous commutator from the left and right particles must vanish:
$$
\tag 3 [E_{i}(\mathbf x), E_{j}(\mathbf y)]_{L\oplus R} = -i\Delta^{ij}_{L}(\mathbf A, \mathbf y)\delta (\mathbf x - \mathbf y)-i\Delta^{ij}_{R}(\mathbf A, \mathbf y)\delta (\mathbf x - \mathbf y) = 0
$$

**My question is following**. Although the anomalous commutator $(0)$ exists on subspaces $L$ and $R$, it vanishes for their direct sum, as is shown by $(3)$. But the chiral anomaly $(2)$ exists. This means, that there are anomalous commutators in section of chiral-vector currents, i.e., in section of fermion canonical variables. But how to implement this "anomalous commutator" flow from EM field canonical variables to fermion canonical variables?

Comment: What's your question? The anomaly doesn't appear in commutators of fermionic canonical variables. It appears if your consider $\partial_t\langle Q(t)O(x')\rangle$ taking into account interaction

Comment: What I mean is that canonical commutators of simultaneous fermionic operators remain the same

Comment: @OON : but how to recover the chiral anomaly from the above approach?

Comment: @OON : but the axial and vector currents commutator is non-zero in the case of chiral anomaly. This typically means that the canonical variables commutator is modified. Also, I know that semiclassically fermions canonical coordinate and momentum are no longer canonical, when the chiral anomaly appears.

Comment: But you can't unambigously derive commutator with product of fields at the same point (like in current operators) from the field commutation relations because the result happens to be regularization-dependent - Schwinger terms arise. And anomaly in the current commutators arise in the form of Schwinger term so it can happen without any changes to $\{\psi^\dagger(\vec{x}),\psi(\vec{y})\}$

Comment: Is that semiclassical result obtained by you or can you provide a reference?

Comment: @OON : I talked about the semiclassical approximation in a sense that the fermion is treated as the classical particle with given momenta. The more or less popular article about that is this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0747